# Hominid exception error with EOF reached file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using hominid gem for Rails 3 for to connect with MailChimP API. I write a class with many methods for my problem domain.

I need a rake task which run each X time. My problem is when i test the hominid methods. 
Each X time hominid gem raise a exception with EOF Reached file error.

I test my methods many time without to change arguments. sometimes run very well while other times throw this exception.

I also test my methods calling from console and controller action.

There occurs same problem.

How could I sync hominid API calls?
Which could be the problem?

Thanks in advance